# Visa for Romania, Bosnia and Montenegro?

Tags: romania, serbia, montenegro, bosnia, algerian-citizens

I am an Algerian national possessing a Serbian temporary residence. I want to travel from Belgrade to Romania, Bosnia and Montenegro. Do I need a visa for these countries?

Answer (score 2):

You need a visa for Romania, as Algeria is own the list for [*the list of states whose citizens (annex 1), holders of simple passports, are required a visa upon entry on the Romanian territory*](https://www.mae.ro/sites/default/files/file/anul_2019/2019_pdf/anexa_1_en.pdf).

You don’t need a visa for Bosnia if you stay less than 90 days:

> Državljani Rumunije izuzeti su od viznog režima prilikom ulaska, izlaska ili prelaska preko teritorije Bosne i Hercegovine do 90 dana, u periodu od šest mjeseci, počevši od dana prvog ulaska.

(From the visa [website](http://www.mfa.gov.ba/konzularne_informacije/vize/Default.aspx?template_id=16&s1=294&id=5079))

When translated:

> Romanian nationals are exempted from the visa regime when entering, exiting or crossing the territory of Bosnia and Herzegovina for up to 90 days, for a period of six months, starting from the date of first entry.

You also need a visa for Montenegro, you can obtain it from the  Serbian consulate. Details of the consulate available [here](https://www.embassypages.com/missions/embassy22053/).

Answer (score -1):

You need a visa for Romania, ask your embassy.  Their site is at:  http://www.ambasada-algeriei.ro

Comment: Wouldn't the Romanian embassy in Belgrade be the more appropriate place to ask?